# UIView doesn't change at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I've had this working in other variations but something seems to elude me in the change from objective-c to swift as well as moving some of the setup into it's own class.

So i have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, interfaceDelegate, scrollChangeDelegate{
    let scrollControl = scrollMethods()
    let userinterface = interface()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadMenu("Start")
    }

    func loadMenu(menuName: String) {

        userinterface.delegate = self
        userinterface.scrollDelegate = self   
        userinterface.removeFromSuperview() //no impact
        scrollControl.removeFromSuperview() //no impact
        userinterface.configureView(menuName)       
        view.addSubview(scrollControl)
        scrollControl.addSubview(userinterface)
    }
}
```

This sets everything up correctly but the problem occurs when I change `loadMenu()` at runtime. So if the user calls `loadMenu("AnotherMenu")` it won't change the `UIView`. It will call the right functions but it won't update the view. Although if I call `loadMenu("AnotherMenu")` at the start, the correct menu will display. Or if I call `loadMenu("Start")` and then `loadMenu("AnotherMenu")` then the menu displayed will be "AnotherMenu". As in:

```
 override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadMenu("Start")
    loadMenu("AnotherMenu")
}
```

When I list all the subviews each time `loadMenu()` is called, they look correct. Even during runtime. But the display is not updated. So something isn't getting the word. I've tried disabling Auto Layout after searching for similar issues but didn't see a difference.

Comment: Where are these views created?  If you are creating them in the interface builder then you need to create `@IBOutlet` properties and hook them up in the interface builder.

Comment: They are created programmatically in interface(). The buttons function and everything seems to work right. Even listing the subviews seems to indicate the correct UIView is there. But I can't get it to display.

Comment: You should show the code for `userinterface.configureView(menuName)`

Comment: Are `scrollMethods()` and `interface()` functions or class initializers?  You should add the code for them.

Comment: they are for a uiscrollview and uiview class. I'll create a dummy class and see if it's related or still causing the issue.

Comment: Just a consideration: it does not shows or it shows on a lower z-index? Try to insertSubView(at index).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding setNeedsDisplay() to loadMenu

Eg

```
  func loadMenu(menuName: String) {

    userinterface.delegate = self
    userinterface.scrollDelegate = self   
    userinterface.removeFromSuperview() //no impact
    scrollControl.removeFromSuperview() //no impact
    userinterface.configureView(menuName)       
    view.addSubview(scrollControl)
    scrollControl.addSubview(userinterface)
    view.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

setNeedsDisplay() forces the view to reload the user interface.

Comment: I tried that as well. No luck. Although it seems like it should work.

Comment: Hmm, try adding the userinterface view to scrollView first. I always do that, don't know why haha.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to post the whole `UIView` class as it is long and I thought unrelated. But Dan was right that he would need to know what was going on in those to figure out the answer. So I created a dummy `UIView` class to stand in and intended to update the question with that. I then just put a button on the ViewController's `UIView`. That button was able to act on the view created by the dummy. So the problem was in the other class. Yet it was calling the methods of the ViewController and seemingly worked otherwise. So then the issue must be that its acting on an instanced version? The way the uiview class worked, it uses `performSelector()`. But in making these methods into their own class, I had just lazily wrote

```
(ViewController() as NSObjectProtocol).performSelector(selector)
```

when it should have been

```
(delegate as! NSObjectProtocol).performSelector(selector)
```

so that was annoying and I wasted the better part of a day on that. But thanks again for the help.